# How to set up line integral of electric field? Confused over notation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, calculus

In multivariable calculus the line integrals was parameterized and denoted: 
$$
\int_C \mathbf{F} \bullet \, d\mathbf{r}=\int_D\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t)) \bullet \frac{d \mathbf{r}(t)}{dt} \, dt
$$
However in electromagnetism the line integrals are confusing. The electric field:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}(t))=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \int_{path} \frac{\lambda(\mathbf{r}')}{\lvert \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \rvert^2} 
\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{\lvert \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'} \rvert} \, dl'
$$
$\mathbf{r}$ = field point and $\mathbf{r'}$ = source point of the charge.

What is the difference between this two integrals? Is the second a line integral along a vector field?

In math the procedure was; parametrize the curve, take the derivative of it, dot it with the parameterized field.

Should a parametrize the electric field or not?

I also have problem setting up the differential line element $dl'$. What is $d\mathbf{r}$ equivalent to in the second integral?

Answer (score 1):

$dl'$ is equivalent to "$d|\mathbf{r}|$", it is essentially a "scalar length measure".

The electrodynamics integral you wrote here is a vector-valued integral, so no dotting happens. If you use a linear coordinate system, it may be evaluated as three scalar line integrals, one for each coordinate. Vector valued integrals cannot really be evaluated using a curved coordinate system.

Your integral should be evaluated as follows: $\mathbf{r}'$ is actually a curve $\mathbf{r}'(t)$ (I am not going to use ' as a notation for derivatives), and your integral is $$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\kappa\int_\gamma\frac{\lambda(\mathbf{r}'(t))}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(t)|^2}\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(t)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(t)|}\left|\frac{d\mathbf{r}'(t)}{dt}\right|dt. $$

Note that whilst I do not know the full context, from the form of the integral I can infer that only $\mathbf{r}'$ is parametrized by $t$. You are asking the value of $\mathbf{E}$ at a single point ($\mathbf{r}$), and this value is given by integrating the $\mathbf{r}'$ variable over a curve.

---

**Edit:** To answer your comment, you are almost correct.

Now that I know the full case, you also need to parametrize the $\mathbf{r}$ variable, *but only because you are interested in values of $E$ solely on the $z$ axis*!

Let us calculate the relevant vector quantities:

$$\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(z)=z\mathbf{e}_z$$ (I am using the generic $z$ as a parameter instead of $b$, since I think this way it is clearer.) $$\mathbf{r}'(t)=a\cos(t)\mathbf{e}_x+a\sin(t)\mathbf{e}_y, $$ $$ \mathbf{r}(z)-\mathbf{r}'(t)=-a\cos(t)\mathbf{e}_x-a\sin(t)\mathbf{e}_y+z\mathbf{e}_z, $$ $$|\mathbf{r}(z)-\mathbf{r}'(t)|^2=a^2+z^2, $$ $$ \frac{d\mathbf{r}'(t)}{dt}=-a\sin(t)\mathbf{e}_x+a\cos(t)\mathbf{e}_y, $$ $$\left|\frac{d\mathbf{r}'(t)}{dt}\right|=a. $$

Now the integral is (since $\lambda$ is constant) $$ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}(z))=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_\gamma\frac{1}{a^2+z^2}\left(-\frac{a\cos(t)}{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}}\mathbf{e}_x-\frac{a\sin(t)}{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}}\mathbf{e}_y+\frac{z}{\sqrt{a^2+z^2}}\mathbf{e}_z\right)a\ dt=\\\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{a}{(a^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}z\ dt\mathbf{e}_z=\frac{\lambda}{2\epsilon_0}\frac{az}{(a^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\mathbf{e}_z, $$ where the $\mathbf{e}_x$ and $\mathbf{e}_y$ integrals are annihilated because $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are integrated on their full period.

Comment: Great, thanks! Shouln't $\mathbf{r}$ be parameterized (a function of $t$), i.e. $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(t)$?

Comment: I had problem with this question:
A uniform line charge density $\lambda$ forms a circle of radius $a$ in the $xy$-plane ($z = 0$),
with the center at the origin. Find the electric field at point $(0,0,b)$.
Solution: ($\mathbf{r'}(t))$ is the source point, not the derivative)
I don't really know there to start.
Is the curve the same as the source point $\mathbf{r'}(t)$?
Should I parametrize the circle in the $xy$-plane?
If $x^2+y^2=a^2$, let $x(t)=\cos t , y(t)=\sin t, t\to[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: The position vectors are (parameterized)
$$
\mathbf{r}(t)=b{\mathbf{\hat{z}}}
$$
$$
\mathbf{r'}(t)=a(\cos t \,{\mathbf{\hat{x}}} +\sin t \, {\mathbf{\hat{y}}})
$$
$$
\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r'}(t)= b{\mathbf{\hat{z}}} - a(\cos t \,{\mathbf{\hat{z}}}+\sin t \, {\mathbf{\hat{y}}})
$$

Is this right? I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: @JDoeDoe I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it! :) For surface charge density, is this correct (in terms of parameters and excluding parameterization of $\mathbf{r}$)

$$
\mathbf{E(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \iint_{S} \frac{\sigma(\mathbf{r}'(s,t))}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(s,t)|^2} 
\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(s,t)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(s,t)|} 
\biggl \lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}'(s,t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}'(s,t)}{\partial t}
\biggl \rvert \, ds \, dt
$$

Comment: And for volume charge density? $u, v, w$ are parameters.
$$
\mathbf{E(r)}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \iiint_{V} \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}'(u,v,w))}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(u,v,w)|^2} 
\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(u,v,w)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(u,v,w)|} 
\lvert
\textit{something} 
\rvert
\, du \, du \, dw
$$

Comment: @JDoeDoe Yes, it is correct, provided $|\text{something}|$ is the jacobian determinant.

Comment: Great! For a multivariable position vector does $\mathbf{r'}(u,v,w)$ imply:
$$\mathbf{r'}(u,v,w)=x'(u,v,w)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+y'(u,v,w)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y+z'(u,v,w)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z$$ ? If true the Jacobian determinant (volume integral) is
 $$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)}$$
However, for the surface integral with $\mathbf{r'}(s,t)=x'(s,t)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+y'(s,t){\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y}+z'(s,t){\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z}$, the Jacobian det. $\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(s,t)}$ doesn't make sense....?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Your formula was correct for the surface integral, I only said the "something" in your volume integral was the jacobian.

Comment: @JDoeDoe There is no jacobian determinant in the surface integral. There is only the contribution area from the parameters $s$ and $t$ already specified by your formula as that cross product. I.e:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial\mathbb r'}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\mathbb r'}{\partial t}\right|dsdt
$$

Comment: Should $ \big \lvert\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}'(s,t)}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}'(s,t)}{\partial t} \big \rvert \, ds \, dt$ work in 3D (if $\mathbf{r}=x\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+y\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y+z\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z$)? I tested a problem with a spherical surface, radius $R$, and with a uniform surface charges density $\sigma$. ''Find the electric field at distance $a$ along the $z$-axis". The parameterization:
$$
\mathbf{r}=a\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z
$$

Comment: $$\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)=R\sin \theta\cos\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+R\sin \theta\sin\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y+R\cos \theta\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z
$$$$
\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{dR}=\sin\theta\cos\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+\sin\theta\sin\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y+\cos\theta\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z
$$$$\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\theta}=R\cos\theta\cos\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+R\cos\theta\sin\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y-R\sin\theta\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z
$$$$
\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{dR} \times \frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\theta}=-R\sin\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+R\cos \phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y
$$

Comment: $$
\biggl \lvert\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{dR} \times \frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\theta} \biggl \rvert=R 
$$
I can post the whole problem, however, shouldn't the surface integral-parameterization work in 3D? @Physicist137

Comment: Just for testing: 
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\phi}=-R\sin\theta\sin\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+R\sin\theta\cos\phi\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y
$$$$
(\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{dR} \times \frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\theta}) \times (\frac{d\mathbf{r'}(R,\theta,\phi)}{d\phi})=\mathbf{0} $$@Uldreth

Comment: @JDoeDoe, You used $R$ as a parameter. Its not. $R$ is a constant, because as you said, its a spherical surface. If $R$ were a parameter, it would be a ball, a volumetric space, not a surface. And one cannot compute a surface integral from a volumetric space... Thus, there is only $\mathbf r(\theta, \phi)$ in your example. And then, only one cross product. Your questions seems to be mathematical in origin, about evaluation of surface and volume integrals. Perhaps you should try [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). =). And yes, that cross product works with surfaces inside 3D space.

Comment: @Physicist137 Thanks, got it now! I thought that a spherical paramtrization was $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(R,\theta,\phi)$, but true, a surface have only two parameters.